# change text in listbox without changing values

Tags: c#, listbox

i have a listbox that adds the ids from a dictionary to the listbox but i need it to display the name and not the id but the value of the item has to be the id is there any way to do this heres the code i use

```
    public static Dictionary<int, CardInfos> CardDataeff = new Dictionary<int, CardInfos>();


    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (Searchlock)
        {
            if (textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                listBox2.Items.Clear();
                return;
            }
            if (textBox2.Text != "Search")
            {
                listBox2.Items.Clear();
                foreach (int card in CardDataeff.Keys)
                {
                    if (CardDataeff[card].Id.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith(textBox2.Text.ToLower()) ||
                        CardDataeff[card].Name.ToLower().Contains(textBox2.Text.ToLower()))
                    {
                        listBox2.Items.Add(CardDataeff[card].Id.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

  public void listBox2_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();

        bool selected = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected);

        int index = e.Index;
        if (index >= 0 && index < listBox2.Items.Count)
        {
            string text = listBox2.Items[index].ToString();
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            CardInfos card = CardDataeff[Int32.Parse(text)];

            g.FillRectangle((selected) ? new SolidBrush(Color.Blue) : new SolidBrush(Color.White), e.Bounds);

            // Print text
            g.DrawString((card.Name == "" ? card.Id.ToString() : card.Name), e.Font, (selected) ? Brushes.White : Brushes.Black,
                listBox2.GetItemRectangle(index).Location);
        }

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }

    private bool LoadCard(int cardid)
    {
        if (!CardDataeff.ContainsKey(cardid))
        {
            return false;
        }

        CardInfos info = CardDataeff[cardid];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.richTextBox1.Text))
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("do you want to save? ", "Prompt", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.filePath))
                {
                    this.saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = this.scriptFolderPath;
                    this.saveFileDialog1.FileName = this.getFileName();
                    if (this.saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
                        this.saveFile(this.saveFileDialog1.FileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.saveFile(this.filePath);
                }
            } 
        }
        this.openFile(cdbdir + "\\script\\c" + cardid + ".lua");
        return true;
    }


    private void listBox2_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox list = (ListBox)sender;
        if (list.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            LoadCard(Int32.Parse(list.SelectedItem.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

i included all code that i think is necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you can set items.Tag property your id and Text property your Value. Actually this is purpose of the Tag property.To do this you can consider using ListView instead of listBox.

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.Text = CardDataeff[card].Name;
item.Tag = CardDataeff[card].Id
listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

Then when you need get item id:

```
int id = (int)listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag;
```

Comment: for some reason my comments werent working with your code i get this error   Error 18 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedItem' and no extension method 'SelectedItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: nvm fixed that error by doing this  int id = (int)listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag;

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the `displayMember` and `valueMember` properties of the ListBox, and bind it to a collection rather than adding the elements individually.